# How can I change the text of a input box?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this JS to try to set the text of a input box to nothing when the user clicks the clear button

```
// This code is not inside of the clearText function
var input = document.getElementById("input");

// this code is inside of the clearText function
input.innerHTML = "";
```

Here is the HTML I used for the input box and clear button:

```
<input id="input" type="text">

<button onclick="clearText()">Clear Factors</button>
```

What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out `input.value = "";` Inputs are a little different then an element such as a p where the innerHTML would work as you expect. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: @fredrikapps I had planned on doing just that lol! I had to wait the 12 minutes 'till I could though